# Can I bring my wife with me to Italy if I get a student visa?

Tags: visa, study, italy, dependent-visa

I applied to several universities for a Ph.D. position in Italy. The probability of getting admission from one of them is high. If I get admission it will follow by a scholarship. I am an Iranian resident and definitely need a student visa. I am married and want to bring my wife myself. A friend of mine told that the Italian embassy in Iran will not issue a visa for my wife. I visit the Italian embassy website in Iran and find no enough information about the above-mentioned subject. My friend said that I have to go first and show my financial strength that I can support my wife and then send an invitation to my spouse and it may take a while to get a visa for my wife. My friend said that my wife may fail to get a visa to join me. **Is this how the Italian embassy works?** , separate the family members? As far as I know other countries, for instance, Canada, Sweden, Germany, Australia,... issue visas for the whole member of a student's family when the student gets a visa.  I am among those middle-class family and I have enough money to support my wife for 3 years, besides my father-in-law is a publisher and have the good fortune to support us if we get into trouble, I don't know this help or not?

Comment: You should probably talk to someone at the embassy. Or the universities you are applying to will probably have international student offices that will know the rules too. e.g. here's the [Unibo page for international research staff with families](https://www.unibo.it/en/international/international-staff-professors-and-researchers/information-for-international-teaching-and-research-staff-hosted-at-the-university-of-bologna/travelling-with-your-family) (though I realise you probably don't count as staff)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Rup. That was extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply for the family reunion visa for your wife once you have obtained your own authorization (nulla osta) even before you get your own visa.

To do this, you can get an appointment in the Italian embassy in Iran. The application form will be the long-term visa application form- similar as yours. The main documents that they ask for are the nulla osta, marriage certificate, and proof of funds as well as proof of accommodation.

As far as income goes, you must demonstrate an income of no less than the annual amount of the social allowance. I believe it's close to 5800 euros per year. It changes every year.

Most of the Italian embassies don't have much information about visas on their websites.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment thetravelgirl, I really appreciate your advice, those were extremely useful.